# Asp.net mvc core bought template button custom onClick event at Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

my problem is that I want to add a button from this template:
https://designreset.com/cork-admin-v1/ltr/demo3/element_buttons.html

If I click on a button I want to run a function at my controller, how can I do this?
Already tried it with code like that:

```
<button type="button" onclick='location.href=@Url.Action("redirect","Login")'" class="btn btn-info mb-2">Info</button>
```

This is not working. I also tried it with javascript, this works but I don't think that that is the best way.

```
<span onclick="login()" class="btn btn-primary" value="">Log In</span>"
<script>
    function login() {
        
        let userName = $('.userName').val();
        let password = $('.password').val();
        $.ajax({
            url: '/login/login?userName=' + userName + '&&password=' + password,
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                alert(data);
                window.location.href = "/login/home";
            },
            error: function (resp) {
                alert(resp);
                console.log(resp);
            }

        });
    }
</script>
```

Could someone say me if I need to do this really with javascript?
Or can I directly call the controller action, when yes, how?

**EDIT:**

With the following code it seems to work:

```
<button type="submit" asp-action="redirect" class="btn btn-info mb-2">Info</button>
```

Comment: To submit form data to specific controller and action in  ASP.NET Core, you can check this doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/working-with-forms?view=aspnetcore-5.0#submit-to-controller-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead for ASP.NET MVC 5:

```
<button type="button" onclick="window.location='@Url.Action("ActionName", "ControllerName")'" class="btn btn-info mb-2">Info</button>
```

For ASP.NET Core, your code is correct,

```
<button type="submit" asp-action="redirect" asp-controller="ControllerNameHere" class="btn btn-info mb-2">Info</button>
```

Additional details can be also specified like passing values on the Controller:

```
<button type="submit" asp-action="redirect" asp-controller="ControllerNameHere" asp-route-AnyId="@Model.AnyId" class="btn btn-info mb-2">Info</button>
```

Comment: Nothing happens, i got it to work now with 
<button type="submit" asp-action="MyAction" class="btn btn-info mb-2">Info</button>

Is this solution fine?

Comment: I apologize, I thought your question is related to ASP.NET MVC 5, I updated my answer which is related to your targeted .NET framework.